# BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I suddenly got this error while working on my umbraco website

```
BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection'
```

Did anyone have the same issue? Tried searching different thread in SO but failed to get the solution from a typical BadImageFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing it from my assembly.

```
<remove assembly="System.Net.WebHeaderCollection" />
```

Then I got another assembly error for System.Runtime.Handles so I removed it too

```
<remove assembly="System.Runtime.Handles" />
```

Its working for now. I will come back to this answer if there is any complication. Here's the markup in web.config

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" batch="false" targetFramework="4.6" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50">
    <assemblies>
        ...
        <remove assembly="System.Net.WebHeaderCollection" />
        <remove assembly="System.Runtime.Handles" />
        ...
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```